# Image crop is not working in android 7.0

Tags: android

Application getting crashed in android 7.0 when i crop the image.

Exception :
02-06 12:40:53.717 5671-5685/com.tribyte.iTutor2 E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                                  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing android.support.v4.content.FileProvider uri content://com.tribyte.iTutor2.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.tribyte.iTutor2/files/Application/sites/default/files/askexpertimages/325590_user1aipmt@gmail.com_1486365038955_crop.png from pid=6784, uid=10105 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceWritePermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:682)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceWritePermission(ContentProvider.java:497)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:469)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:384)
                                                                      at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:262)
                                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)

Sample code:

```
private void performCrop()
{
try 
{
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
this.grantUriPermission(packageName, temppicUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}

String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(picUri.toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

intent.setDataAndType(picUri,mimetype);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, temppicUri);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 512);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
//start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
{
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);   
startActivityForResult(intent, PIC_CROP);
}
}
catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
{
//display an error message
String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
}    
}
```

Comment: Have you set WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest?

Comment: I have given the the permission for READ/WRITE external storage.

Answer (score -1):

In my limited experience, I think it's caused by OOM.The code is as follows,

`intent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 512);`

The size of 512*512 is too large in the higher quality device with greater screen resolution. You can reduce the size of the image if it's large.